Matlab warning unable to calculate convolution of piecewise function
I am working with Matlab and I am trying to find the convolution of 2 piecewise functions.My first function is x(t) is a periodic function with sines and cosines and the 2nd function h(t) is a piecewise function of straight lines.
Here is the code:
clc 

clear

syms t k v real;





h(t) = piecewise((t<1)&(t>=0),1,(t>=1)&(t<2),3*t-1,(t<3)&(t>=2),0,(t>=3)&(t<4),t-3,(t>=4)&(t<5),5-t,0);

x(t) = piecewise((t<=1)&(t>=0),5+4*cos(4*pi*t)+5*sin(70*pi*t),0);

h1(t) = piecewise((t<1)&(t>=0),1,0);

h2(t) = piecewise((t>=1)&(t<2),3*t-1,0);

h3(t) = piecewise((t>=3)&(t<4),t-3,0);

h4(t) = piecewise((t>=4)&(t<5),5-t,0);

c1(t) = int(x(k)*h1(t-k),k,-inf,inf);

c2(t) = int(x(k)*h2(t-k),k,-inf,inf);

c3(t) = int(x(k)*h3(t-k),k,-inf,inf);

c4(t) = int(x(k)*h4(t-k),k,-inf,inf);

c(t) = c1+c2+c3+c4;


H(v) = int(h(t)*exp(-1i*v*t),t,-inf,inf);

disp(H);

X(v) = int(x(t)*exp(-1i*v*t),t,-inf,inf);

disp(X);

subplot(1,2,1);

fplot(v,real(X));

title("Real part of X(v)");

subplot(1,2,2);

fplot(v,imag(X));

title("Imaginary part of X(v)");

C(v) = H(v)*X(v);

subplot(1,2,1);

fplot(t,real(c));

title("Real part of c(t)");

subplot(1,2,2);

fplot(t,imag(c));

title("Imaginary part of c(t)");

my target function is c(t) the rest of the code is for one of my exercises.
I had attempted to directly calculate the convolution of x(t) with h(t) by having used this line code:
c(t) = int(x(k)*h(t-k),k,-inf,inf);
before I splited h into 4 functions h1,h2,h3 and h4 where obviously h = h1+h2+h3+h4
But no matter what I do this error keeps popping up:
Warning: Unable to check whether the integrand exists everywhere on the integration interval. 
> In symengine
  In sym/int (line 162)
  In firstErg (line 23) 
Warning: Unable to check whether the integrand exists everywhere on the integration interval. 
> In symengine
  In sym/int (line 162)
  In firstErg (line 25) 
Warning: Unable to check whether the integrand exists everywhere on the integration interval. 
> In symengine
  In sym/int (line 162)
  In firstErg (line 27) 
Warning: Unable to check whether the integrand exists everywhere on the integration interval. 
> In symengine
  In sym/int (line 162)
  In firstErg (line 29) 

How can I solve this out?
